Java WeakHashMap leak when value references key
I have a WeakHashMap where the value may reference the key and this will cause a memory leak because the value is hold as Strong reference and thus the key will be Strongly reachable.

Is there a way to avoid this without changing the key or the value (I can only wrap them, but not modify their classes)
My ultimate goal is to keep the value from being collected by the GC until the key is strongly reachable. (and I need to access the value)

I’m afraid, there is no solution without changing at least one of the classes.

You could store a weak reference back to the key:
String myValue = "some value";
WeakHashMap<String, WeakReference<String>> myMap = new WeakHashMap<>();
myMap.put(myValue, new WeakReference<>(myValue));


this will not prevent the value from being collected by the GC

@lelmarir Why aren’t you using a regulator HashMap<K, V>?

Because I would like the value to be collected once the key is no longer strongly referenced (excluding the value reference itself). Using a regular HashMap the value will be strongly referenced and thus the key (wich is in turn referenced by the value).
Using a WeakHashMap would work if only the value would not reference the key, but so it does.

As long as a value in a WeakHashMap has a reference to a key, the garbage collector will not be able to collect that key and there will be no memory leaks.

Yes, with "memory leak" I was talking about the fact that I'd like that the value should not keep the key from being collected. To me, this is an unwanted side effect

@lelmarir If a value from your map is wrapped in a WeakReference, or a reference to a key in that value is wrapped in a WeakReference, then the garbage collector will be able to collect your key and value if there are no other references to them.

Yes, but this way the only reference to the value would be the WeakReference and the value would be collected. Instead, I want the value to be kept until the key is referenced by someone (excluding the value itself) and prevent the value from keeping the key if it's the only remaining reference.
